# Citing ‘InCollection’ with IEEE style of BibLaTeX: incorrectly formated part

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, ieee-style

Consider this example:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{Bibliography.bib}
    @InCollection{Aut19,
      author      = {Author, J.},
      booktitle   = {Book Title},
      date        = {2019-08-26},
      title       = {Title},
      part        = {2},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}   
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The result contains (probably) incorrectly formatted `part` field:

[image: Output]

It is printed as ‘**.**​2’, while in this case I suppose it should rather be something like ‘part 2’, ‘pt. 2’ or just ‘2’ (without the leading period).

Do I need some extra macros to get the appropriate result – or maybe such citations are expected to look like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex` assumes that part relates to a volume that is bound in two parts. So you get "Vol. 2.1" and "Vol. 2.2" for volume 2 part 1 and volume 2 part 2. It doesn't handle a case where the work has only one volume with two parts and you would therefore leave the volume out.

Arguably, this is a bug in `biblatex` (and `biblatex-ieee`).

Three things need to be done to fix this.

- Redefine the field format for `part`.
- Redefine the `volume+part` macro.
- Patch the `incollection` driver, which (oddly) is the only one which does not use the `volume+part` macro.

I don't think there should be any side affects, but check your references that use `volume` and `part` carefully to make sure.

## MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{Bibliography.bib}
@InCollection{Aut19,
  author    = {Author, J.},
  booktitle = {Book Title},
  date      = {2019-08-26},
  title     = {Title},
  part      = {2},
}
@InCollection{Aut18,
  author    = {Author, K.},
  booktitle = {Another Book Title},
  date      = {2018-08-26},
  title     = {Another Title},
  volume    = {4},
  part      = {2},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\printfield{volume}\printfield{part}}
  {\usebibmacro{volume+part}}
  {}
  {}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+part}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\addperiod}%
  \iffieldundef{volume}
    {\printfield{part}}
    {\printfield[default]{part}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{part}{\bibstring{part}~#1}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]